# What are nested objects in OOP concept? (mainly in java)

Tags: java, oop

It was asked in an interview that what are nested objects ? give a real life example also.
I end up saying that if we create an object of class B in class A and when the object of class A will be created then Class A object will already be having Class B object and that's called nested object.

Comment: You are completely right!

Comment: Nested objects are good for organize your class visiblity inside of main class. If you need class which is in context with main class and her purpose is only for her and you never need instanted this class outside of main class its good use this nested "hidden" classes in context of main class.

Answer (score 1):

While you are absolutely right with your answer, here are few more details about it.

The thing you are talking about is actually `Containment` or `HAS-A` relationship. There are two types of containments in OOP.

> Consider `A` `HAS-A` `B`

**Composition:** 
It is a type of containment where `B` cannot exist if `A` dies. Best example is a House `has-a` room. If house is destroyed, room has no existence.

**Aggregation:**
It is a type of containment where `B` can still exist even if `A` dies. Example for this is 
Employee `has-a` department. Even if employee is destroyed, the department will still exist

Comment: Containment is not composition (has-a). For composition you can define the other object anywhere.  Nested objects are probably inner classes in Java. Also, as a counter example: If I have a car which has-a set of tires, the tires can exist after the car is gone. I can put them on another car, or make them a swing for the kids.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Containment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Containment_(computer_programming)). I don't see any reason why Composition is not Containment. There is a difference between Nested Classes and Nested Objects. OP has referred to Nested Objects and not classes. I don't think my answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote you... and you may be right...I may have misunderstood the question. Now I am unsure if the question is about composition or inner classes.